# mac-address in local network with (javaScript or PHP)

Tags: javascript, php, mac-address

So as far as I know, I cannot get the mac-address with javascript or php - except for some IE users and only if they have activeX.

BUT here are 2 similar scenarios:
And i think these are not duplicate questions...

1) Can I get the mac-address of EVERY user (windows, android, apple, etc.) if the website is hosted locally and people access a form via wifi?
And if yes, can this be done with php/javascript?

2) Can I get the mac-address of EVERY user (windows, android, apple, etc.) if I only want to track users from ONE network, but the site is hosted on some linux server somewhere else? And if yes, can this be done with php/javascript?

• In case you need to know why I want to do this: This is for an online draw at a night club and we would like track mac-addresses, so you can only sign up once with every device.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I get the mac-address of EVERY user (windows, android, apple,
>   etc.) if I only want to track users from ONE network, but the site is
>   hosted on some linux server somewhere else? And if yes, can this be
>   done with php/javascript?

This is generally not possible.

> Can I get the mac-address of EVERY user (windows, android, apple,
>   etc.) if the website is hosted locally and people access a form via
>   wifi? And if yes, can this be done with php/javascript?

If the the web clients are on the same subnet as the server you could read the mappings from the ARP table. On Linux open the text file `/proc/net/arp` using your PHP script and lookup the MAC address using the provided `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`.

> In case you need to know why I want to do this: This is for an online
>   draw at a night club and we would like track mac-addresses, so you can
>   only sign up once with every device.

On a local network, you gain no security by filtering on MAC addresses instead of IP addresses. A host's MAC address is trivial to change on most platforms.